# convert model to viewmodel

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a table name "Product" and another table name "category".
Product table has 'productID', 'productName' and 'CategoryID'.
Category table has 'categoryID' and 'categoryName'.

My target is to display a list of products with category. The list will contain 'product id', 'product name' and 'category name'.

I have created a viewmodel. the code is

```
public int prodID{get;set;}
public int prodName{get;set;}
public int catName{get;set;}
```

In my controller, I have:

```
var query= from p in dc.Product
                      select new {p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.Category1.CategoryName };
var prod = new ProductIndexViewModel()
        {
            ProductList=query //this line is problematic !!it says an explicit conversion exists....
        };
        return View(prod);
```

How would I write my controller code so that it matches with the viewmodel??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you will use your view model class directly:

```
       var query = from p in dc.Product
                    select new ProductIndexViewModel() { 
                        prodID = p.ProductID, 
                        prodName = p.ProductName, 
                        catName = p.Category1.CategoryName 
                    };

        List<ProductIndexViewModel> productForView = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) instead of rewriting properties from db model.

```
var viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel()
{  
    ProductList = dc.Product.ToList().Select(product => Mapper.Map<Product, ProductViewModel>(product));
}
```

Comment: I'm using Automapper in WCF but i'm not able to map Entity model with Model of data contract,what i should do?? This is what i tried:                                           `requestDC = dbEntity.RequestDetails.ToList().Select(req => Mapper.Map<dbEntity.RequestDetails,RequestDC>(req));`  //I'm not able to access dbEntity.RequestDetails under Mapper.Map

Answer (score 1):

Should `prodName` and `catName` be strings?

Also, why not just do this:

```
var viewModel = dc.Product
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new ProductIndexViewModel { prodID = x.ProductId, ... }

return View(viewModel);
```